# Can the nest cam api calls be made using python?

Tags: nest-api

My task is to integrate the Nest Cam with a python code. When nest Cam detects a motion , it should then take a picture and send it to my python code for further processing. How this task can be achieved ?

Comment: Have you looked at the API documentation? https://developer.nest.com

Answer (score 0):

Nest has provided a sample means of Authenticating with the API for python at
   https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/sample-code-auth

You can then poll the Camera using the API for a change to the last_event object 
   https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview#last_event-cam
and if it has changed, you can request the snapshot web_url and download the picture.

There are limits of 2 snapshots per minute if you do not have Nest Aware and 10 snapshops per minute if you do have Nest Aware. There are some other polling limits so you will want to read the API docs to ensure you don't go over them.